# What is the proper length and format for public keys on NEAR

Tags: nearprotocol

Some public keys that are generated from storage devices are 44 characters after the `ed25519:` prefix (52 total) and some are 43 characters (51 total). Is this permissable?

Is the `ed25519:` prefix necessary to include whenever using a public key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ed25519:` prefix is usually optional and is applied by default.

It is ok for keys to have different length. A key is basically a large binary number encoded using base58 with leading zeros being dropped.

Basically the same thing happening as if we had keys encoded in decimal and one key would be `999` while another key is `1001`.