# How do you generate a valid keypair for NEAR protocol from the command line?

Tags: nearprotocol

I'd like to generate a public/private keypair from the command line which I can use for local testing with a NEAR Protocol account.  How is this done?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to generate keys for custody purposes. See [custody docs](https://docs.near.org/docs/tokens/token-custody) for examples.  From the docs:

> Generally, any software that can produce valid ed25519 key pair can be used to generate the keys.

To generate a straightforward keypair (see [format requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64325321/what-is-the-proper-length-and-format-for-public-keys-on-near)), where both public and private key will be available in plaintext to you, you can use the [near command line tools](https://github.com/near/near-cli) to output a keypair for an account (once you've installed them):

```
NEAR_ENV=mainnet near generate-key your-account-name
```

This creates a json keypair at `~/.near-credentials/mainnet/your-account-name.json`

`mainnet` is the network this will be used with by default and also the folder within which the JSON file will live.

If you don't specify an account, one will be automatically generated, for example:

```
NEAR_ENV=mainnet near generate-key
Key pair with ed25519:6okNNRWxvWAyWMYxmgBQ2EWPyRm1FfppgXXWJELrFLXh public key for an account "5644304e7a48c7d425ffdaef027f1dfbd32eab129954b798eae501b610f3b680"
```

If you peek into the generated JSON file, which lives at ``~/.near-credentials/mainnet/5644304e7a48c7d425ffdaef027f1dfbd32eab129954b798eae501b610f3b680.json`, it looks like this:

```
{"account_id":"5644304e7a48c7d425ffdaef027f1dfbd32eab129954b798eae501b610f3b680","public_key":"ed25519:6okNNRWxvWAyWMYxmgBQ2EWPyRm1FfppgXXWJELrFLXh","private_key":"ed25519:5NDP1t4JijZHZzGnEkz3dancSWsLG3Gjss4WPXNPiHWNtdtvVJttW9uPqvxKMCwwPgtYvTxzQqDE7mSN72wXsMcK"}
```

The keypair generated each time is different, but the JSON files persist. And, yes, the keypair displayed above is purely for demonstration purposes and isn't linked to anything interesting :) (don't go sharing real keypairs on the internet, folks).

Troubeshooting -- you may need to double check your permissions to create or write to the `~/.near-credentials` directory to make this work properly.